# How to format the corner plot in python?

Tags: python, plot, mcmc

I have some package like `emcee` which runs `mcmc` algorithm for my model fitting. Once I have the postsample chain, I use the package `corner` to produce `corner` plot. Some of my parameters are very large number while others are small numbers. Because of this, the plot looks very weird (shown in the figure attached).[image]

Is there a way to display large numbers in scientific notation while small number as float? The x-axis tick label already has this. I would like the same for the fit result titles.

Answer (score 4):

### Use `title_fmt`

You can format the title with the kwarg `title_fmt`:

> title_fmt : string
>
> ```
>     The format string for the quantiles given in titles. If you explicitly
>     set ``show_titles=True`` and ``title_fmt=None``, the labels will be
>     shown as the titles. (default: ``.2f``)
> ```

In your case, you might set `title_fmt=".2E"`

### Example

#### Before specifying  `title_fmt`:

[image: before]

#### After specifying  `title_fmt=".2E"`:

[image: after]

### Code for example

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Corner on top of each other"""
import corner
import matplotlib.lines as mlines
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

CORNER_KWARGS = dict(
    smooth=0.9,
    label_kwargs=dict(fontsize=16),
    title_kwargs=dict(fontsize=16),
    quantiles=[0.16, 0.84],
    levels=(1 - np.exp(-0.5), 1 - np.exp(-2), 1 - np.exp(-9 / 2.)),
    plot_density=False,
    plot_datapoints=False,
    fill_contours=True,
    show_titles=True,
    max_n_ticks=3,
    title_fmt=".2E"
)


def overlaid_corner(samples_list, sample_labels):
    """Plots multiple corners on top of each other"""
    # get some constants
    n = len(samples_list)
    _, ndim = samples_list[0].shape
    max_len = max([len(s) for s in samples_list])
    cmap = plt.cm.get_cmap('gist_rainbow', n)
    colors = [cmap(i) for i in range(n)]

    plot_range = []
    for dim in range(ndim):
        plot_range.append(
            [
                min([min(samples_list[i].T[dim]) for i in range(n)]),
                max([max(samples_list[i].T[dim]) for i in range(n)]),
            ]
        )

    CORNER_KWARGS.update(range=plot_range)

    fig = corner.corner(
        samples_list[0],
        color=colors[0],
        **CORNER_KWARGS
    )

    for idx in range(1, n):
        fig = corner.corner(
            samples_list[idx],
            fig=fig,
            weights=get_normalisation_weight(len(samples_list[idx]), max_len),
            color=colors[idx],
            **CORNER_KWARGS
        )

    plt.legend(
        handles=[
            mlines.Line2D([], [], color=colors[i], label=sample_labels[i])
            for i in range(n)
        ],
        fontsize=20, frameon=False,
        bbox_to_anchor=(1, ndim), loc="upper right"
    )
    plt.savefig("orig_corner.png")
    plt.close()


def get_normalisation_weight(len_current_samples, len_of_longest_samples):
    return np.ones(len_current_samples) * (len_of_longest_samples / len_current_samples)


def main():
    ndim, nsamples = 3, 10000
    np.random.seed(2000)
    samples = np.random.randn(ndim * nsamples).reshape([nsamples, ndim]) * 1e9

    overlaid_corner(
        [samples * 3, samples * 2, samples],
        ["samples x 3", "samples x 2", "samples"]
    )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```